# FTP client not connecting to file server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ftp, webserver, fileserver

I have installed a ftp server locally. I have a web service running on my web server too. My client class send a byte stream to web service which needs to be uploaded in to a file server. Both web server and file server running locally. When I'm trying to connect to the file server an exception is thrown. It looks the exception is thrown while trying to connect.

```
       FTPClient client = new FTPClient()

        client.connect("ftp.127.0.0.1");
        client.login("username", "password");
```

I'm using Apache commons net library for FTPClient. I want to know whether this is acceptable to access the local file server from local web server. If so, Is there anything wrong on my code to get connection ?

Exception I get is added below

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Firstly, what Exception is being thrown? Show us logs and try to be more descriptive next time :)

Comment: I have added the exception. I wrote a java test class to check whether I can make a connection with same code. This is not from server. I ran it as a java application. But, I am getting this exception. I think something I have to do with code

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is something wrong with your code, not with instance of your FTP Server, then I would recommend to write a test when you would mock FTP server:

Here you'll find a way to mock it:
http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/fakeftpserver-versus-stubftpserver.html

Comment: I managed to fix that issue. I removed that protocol part "ftp." and it connects successfully. But still file upload is not working. It looks setting transferring mode not successfully taken. I can see in server log it is printed as "504 Unknown MODE type".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ftp.127.0.0.1`
use `127.0.0.1`.